# How to display one activity inside another in Android?

Tags: android, android-activity, android-linearlayout

I have one activity and want to display another inside it. Here's my layout:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent">

  <LinearLayout
      android:orientation="horizontal"
      android:layout_width="fill_parent"
      android:layout_height="fill_parent"
      android:layout_weight="1">
  </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

How can I display an `Activity` in inner `LinearLayout` on button click?

Comment: You can have a LinearLayout inside another LinearLayout, no problem in that.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

#### Use one layout for several activities

Layout instance is inflated for each activity using a `setContentView` method, usually in `onCreate`:

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.my_common_layout);
}
```

So there's no problem to use the same `XML` layout for different activities.

#### Display one activity inside another

You can use a `Fragment` API to complete the task.  See full details in [developer's guide](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/fundamentals/fragments.html).

- Declare a layout like that and Android will create fragments for you:

  ```
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
  <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
      android:orientation="vertical"
      android:layout_width="fill_parent"
      android:layout_height="fill_parent">

      <fragment android:name="com.example.MyFragment"
              android:id="@+id/my_fragment"
              android:layout_width="fill_parent"
              android:layout_height="fill_parent"
              android:layout_weight="1" />

  </LinearLayout>
  ```

  Then create a `MyFragment` class and load it when appropriate.
- Create fragments yourself. Do not define the `Fragment` in `XML` layout:

  ```
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
  <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
      android:orientation="vertical"
      android:layout_width="fill_parent"
      android:layout_height="fill_parent"
      android:id="@+id/my_parent_layout">

  </LinearLayout>
  ```

  After your parent `Activity` is created you can add a new `Fragment` in this way:

  ```
  FragmentManager fragmentManager = getFragmentManager()
  FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();
  MyFragment fragment = new MyFragment();
  fragmentTransaction.add(R.id.my_parent_layout, fragment);
  fragmentTransaction.commit();
  ```

  Here `MyFragment` is defined like this:

  ```
  public class MyFragment extends Fragment {
      ...
  }
  ```

If you're targeting below Android 3.0, consider using [support package](http://developer.android.com/sdk/compatibility-library.html) for that.

Comment: could u give me example how to add it dynamically please

Comment: @AMH You can find it here: http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/fundamentals/fragments.html#Adding

Comment: <fragment android:name="com.example.news.ArticleReaderFragment"
            android:id="@+id/viewer"
            android:layout_weight="2"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent" />
   
and I have another activity with name (test) is this code true ,
        FragmentManager fragmentManager = getFragmentManager();
        FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();
        test fragment = new test();
        fragmentTransaction.add(R.layout.viewer, test);
        fragmentTransaction.commit(); is this correct

Comment: sorry I didn't understand so much from the link

Comment: @AMH You should extend `Fragment` instead of `Activity`, i.e. `class test extends Fragment`. Then give an id to your parent `LinearLayout` in `XML` and call it as follows. I added a sample to the answer.

Comment: This describes how to add a fragment to an activity rather than an activity to an activity.

Comment: public class MyFragment extends Fragment {
    ...
}//MyFragment = YourActivity...just said this to help others.

Comment: This describes how to add a fragment to an activity rather than an activity to an activity